# How to resolve cannot find symbol error?

Tags: java, sdk, cognos, cognos-bi

I'm trying to use a Java program provided by [IBM](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21340789). See the code below. When I try to compile this program,

```
C:\Temp>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\javac.exe" GetOrphanMyFolde
rs.java
```

I get an error saying

```
GetOrphanMyFolders.java:96: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable PropEnum
location: class GetOrphanMyFolders
                                 PropEnum.canBurst      ,
                                 ^
GetOrphanMyFolders.java:97: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable PropEnum
location: class GetOrphanMyFolders
                                 PropEnum.capabilities   ,
                                 ^
```

I'm Java noob, what is the cause of this error? The program I'm using is here

```
/**
 * Licensed Material - Property of IBM
 * © Copyright IBM Corp. 2012
 *
 * GetOrphanMyFolders.java
 *
 * Description: Technote 1340789 - SDK Sample: How to recover the My Folders of users that no longer exist in the Authentication Provider
 *
 * Tested with: IBM Cognos BI 10.1.1, IBM Java 5.0, Axis 1.4
 *
 */

import java.util.Vector;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.axis.client.Stub;
import org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement;

import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.BaseClass;
import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.BiBusHeader;
import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.ContentManagerService_PortType;
import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.ContentManagerService_ServiceLocator;
import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.CopyOptions;
import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.PropEnum;
import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.QueryOptions;
import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.SearchPathMultipleObject;
import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.SearchPathSingleObject;
import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.Sort;
import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.UpdateActionEnum;
import com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.XmlEncodedXML;

public class GetOrphanMyFolders
{
    //TODO: change the following variables depending on your installation and setup

    //--- begin changes ----
    private static String dispatcherURL = "http://localhost:9300/p2pd/servlet/dispatch";

    //Change the next three variables to a valid namespace ID as defined in Cognos Configuration and NOT the namespace name
    //Provide a valid user ID and password if Anonymous is disabled
    private static String nameSpaceID   = "Cognos";
    private static String userName      = "admin";
    private static String password      = "password";

    // define where you are copying the orphaned my folders to
    private static String targetLocation = "/content/folder[@name='OrphanedMyFolders']";
    //--- end changes ---

    //Services to be used in the sample
    private ContentManagerService_PortType cmService = null;

    private String[] getAllMyFoldersSearchPaths(String namespaceID)
    {
        String listOfAccountSP [] = null;
        PropEnum props[] = new PropEnum[] {PropEnum.searchPath, PropEnum.defaultName, PropEnum.portalPage};
        Sort sOpt[] = new Sort[]{}; 
        QueryOptions qOpt = new QueryOptions(); 
        try
        {
            // get the template user's Account object. 
            BaseClass template[] = cmService.query(new SearchPathMultipleObject("//folder"), props, sOpt, qOpt);
            listOfAccountSP = new String [template.length];

            for (int x=0;x<template.length;x++)
            {
                if ( template[x].getSearchPath().getValue().indexOf(")/folder[@name='My Folders']")>0 )
                {
                    listOfAccountSP[x]=template[x].getSearchPath().getValue();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listOfAccountSP;
    }

    private PropEnum[] getAllPropEnum ()
      {
        PropEnum properties[] = new PropEnum[]{
                 PropEnum.active, 
                 PropEnum.actualCompletionTime,
                 PropEnum.actualExecutionTime ,
                 PropEnum.advancedSettings ,
                 PropEnum.ancestors ,
                 PropEnum.asOfTime ,
                 PropEnum.base ,
                 PropEnum.brsAffineConnections, 
                 PropEnum.brsMaximumProcesses ,
                 PropEnum.brsNonAffineConnections, 
                 PropEnum.burstKey ,
                 PropEnum.businessPhone,             
                 PropEnum.canBurst      ,       
                 PropEnum.capabilities   ,          
                 PropEnum.capacity        ,     
                 PropEnum.closeConnectionCommands,             
                 PropEnum.closeSessionCommands    ,         
                 PropEnum.configuration            , 
                 PropEnum.connections             ,
                 PropEnum.connectionString         ,    
                 PropEnum.consumers             ,
                 PropEnum.contact             ,
                 PropEnum.contactEMail         ,    
                 PropEnum.contentLocale         ,    
                 PropEnum.creationTime           ,  
                 PropEnum.credential             ,
                 PropEnum.credentialNamespaces    ,         
                 PropEnum.credentials             ,
                 PropEnum.cubeContentName          ,   
                 PropEnum.dailyPeriod             ,
                 PropEnum.data             ,
                 PropEnum.dataBlocks        ,     
                 PropEnum.dataSize           ,  
                 PropEnum.dataType            , 
                 PropEnum.defaultDescription   ,          
                 PropEnum.defaultName           ,  
                 PropEnum.defaultOutputFormat    ,         
                 PropEnum.defaultScreenTip        ,     
                 PropEnum.defaultTriggerDescription,
                 PropEnum.deployedObject ,
                 PropEnum.deployedObjectAncestorDefaultNames, 
                 PropEnum.deployedObjectClass ,
                 PropEnum.deployedObjectDefaultName, 
                 PropEnum.deployedObjectStatus      ,       
                 PropEnum.deployedObjectUsage        ,     
                 PropEnum.deploymentOptions           ,  
                 PropEnum.description             ,
                 PropEnum.disabled             ,
                 PropEnum.dispatcherID          ,   
                 PropEnum.dispatcherPath         ,    
                 PropEnum.displaySequence         ,    
                 PropEnum.email             ,
                 PropEnum.endDate            , 
                 PropEnum.endType             ,
                 PropEnum.eventID             ,
                 PropEnum.everyNPeriods        ,     
                 PropEnum.executionFormat        ,     
                 PropEnum.executionLocale         ,    
                 PropEnum.executionPageDefinition  ,           
                 PropEnum.executionPageOrientation  ,           
                 PropEnum.executionPrompt            , 
                 PropEnum.faxPhone             ,
                 PropEnum.format             ,
                 PropEnum.gateway             ,
                 PropEnum.givenName            , 
                 PropEnum.governors             ,
                 PropEnum.hasChildren            , 
                 PropEnum.hasMessage             ,
                 PropEnum.hasPrompts             ,
                 PropEnum.height             ,
                 PropEnum.homePhone           ,  
                 PropEnum.horizontalElementsRenderingLimit,
                 PropEnum.identity ,
                 PropEnum.isolationLevel, 
                 PropEnum.lastConfigurationModificationTime, 
                 PropEnum.lastPage ,
                 PropEnum.loadBalancingMode, 
                 PropEnum.locale ,
                 PropEnum.location, 
                 PropEnum.members ,
                 PropEnum.message ,
                 PropEnum.metadataModel ,
                 PropEnum.mobilePhone ,
                 PropEnum.model ,
                 PropEnum.modelName ,
                 PropEnum.modificationTime ,
                 PropEnum.monthlyAbsoluteDay ,
                 PropEnum.monthlyRelativeDay ,
                 PropEnum.monthlyRelativeWeek ,
                 PropEnum.name ,
                 PropEnum.namespaceFormat ,
                 PropEnum.objectClass ,
                 PropEnum.openConnectionCommands ,
                 PropEnum.openSessionCommands ,
                 PropEnum.options ,
                 PropEnum.output ,
                 PropEnum.owner ,
                 PropEnum.ownerPassport ,
                 PropEnum.packageBase ,
                 PropEnum.page ,
                 PropEnum.pageOrientation ,
                 PropEnum.pagerPhone ,
                 PropEnum.parameters ,
                 PropEnum.parent ,
                 PropEnum.paths ,
                 PropEnum.permissions ,
                 PropEnum.policies ,
                 PropEnum.portalPage ,
                 PropEnum.position ,
                 PropEnum.postalAddress ,
                 PropEnum.printerAddress ,
                 PropEnum.productLocale ,
                 PropEnum.qualifier ,
                 PropEnum.recipients ,
                 PropEnum.recipientsEMail ,
                 PropEnum.related ,
                 PropEnum.replacement ,
                 PropEnum.requestedExecutionTime ,
                 PropEnum.retentions ,
                 PropEnum.rsAffineConnections ,
                 PropEnum.rsMaximumProcesses ,
                 PropEnum.rsNonAffineConnections ,
                 PropEnum.rsQueueLimit ,
                 PropEnum.runAsOwner ,
                 PropEnum.runningState ,
                 PropEnum.runOptions ,
                 PropEnum.screenTip ,
                 PropEnum.searchPath ,
                 PropEnum.searchPathForURL ,
                 PropEnum.sequencing ,
                 PropEnum.serverGroup ,
                 PropEnum.source ,
                 PropEnum.specification ,
                 PropEnum.startAsActive ,
                 PropEnum.startDate ,
                 PropEnum.state ,
                 PropEnum.status ,
                 PropEnum.stepObject ,
                 PropEnum.surname ,
                 PropEnum.target ,
                 PropEnum.taskID ,
                 PropEnum.timeZoneID ,
                 PropEnum.triggerDescription ,
                 PropEnum.triggerName ,
                 PropEnum.type ,
                 PropEnum.unit ,
                 PropEnum.uri ,
                 PropEnum.usage ,
                 PropEnum.user ,
                 PropEnum.userCapabilities ,
                 PropEnum.userCapability ,
                 PropEnum.userName ,
                 PropEnum.version ,
                 PropEnum.verticalElementsRenderingLimit ,
                 PropEnum.viewed ,
                 PropEnum.weeklyFriday ,
                 PropEnum.weeklyMonday ,
                 PropEnum.weeklySaturday ,
                 PropEnum.weeklySunday ,
                 PropEnum.weeklyThursday ,
                 PropEnum.weeklyTuesday ,
                 PropEnum.weeklyWednesday ,
                 PropEnum.width ,
                 PropEnum.yearlyAbsoluteDay, 
                 PropEnum.yearlyAbsoluteMonth, 
                 PropEnum.yearlyRelativeDay ,
                 PropEnum.yearlyRelativeMonth, 
                 PropEnum.yearlyRelativeWeek ,

        };
        return properties;
      }

    private String[][] getAllCIs(String namespaceID)
    {
        String listOfCIs [][] = null;

        String searchPath = "CAMID('"+namespaceID+"')//account";
        PropEnum props[] = new PropEnum[] {PropEnum.searchPath, PropEnum.defaultName, PropEnum.portalPage};
        Sort sOpt[] = new Sort[]{}; 
        QueryOptions qOpt = new QueryOptions(); 
        try
        {
            // get the template user's Account object. 
            BaseClass template[] = cmService.query(new SearchPathMultipleObject(searchPath), props, sOpt, qOpt);
            listOfCIs = new String [2] [template.length];

            for (int x=0;x<template.length;x++)
            {
                    listOfCIs[0][x]=template[x].getSearchPath().getValue();
                    listOfCIs[1][x]=template[x].getDefaultName().getValue();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return listOfCIs;

    }

    private void moveMF2PF(String path, String targetLocation)
    {
        String userSearchPaths = path ;
        PropEnum props[] = getAllPropEnum();
        String user = path.substring(0, path.indexOf("/folder[@name='My Folders']"));

        try
        {
            //Query the Content Store for all objects in My Folders for user userName
            BaseClass bc[] = cmService.query(new SearchPathMultipleObject(userSearchPaths), props, new Sort[]{}, new QueryOptions());

            if (bc != null && bc.length > 0)
            {
                //copy the folder to Public Folders and rename
                String[] newName={user};
                CopyOptions opt = new CopyOptions();
                opt.setUpdateAction(UpdateActionEnum.replace);
                opt.setRecursive(true);
                cmService.copyRename(bc,new SearchPathSingleObject(targetLocation),newName,opt);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("User " + user+" did not have My Folders. It could be that they have not logged on yet");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Establish a connection to Cognos BI and initialize the different services
     */
    private void connectToCognos() 
    {
        ContentManagerService_ServiceLocator cmServiceLocator = new ContentManagerService_ServiceLocator();

        try 
        {
            cmService = cmServiceLocator.getcontentManagerService(new java.net.URL(dispatcherURL));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logon to Cognos BI using valid credentials information
     */
    private void logon(String nameSpaceID, String userName, String password) 
    {
        StringBuffer credentialXML = new StringBuffer();

        credentialXML.append("<credential>");
        credentialXML.append("<namespace>").append(nameSpaceID).append("</namespace>");
        credentialXML.append("<username>").append(userName).append("</username>");
        credentialXML.append("<password>").append(password).append("</password>");
        credentialXML.append("</credential>");

        String encodedCredentials = credentialXML.toString();
        XmlEncodedXML xmlCredentials = new XmlEncodedXML();
        xmlCredentials.set_value(encodedCredentials);

        try 
        {
            cmService.logon(xmlCredentials, null);
            getSetHeaders();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getSetHeaders()
    {
        String BiBus_NS = "http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/bibus/3/";
        String BiBus_H = "biBusHeader";

        BiBusHeader CMbibus = null;

        SOAPHeaderElement temp = ((Stub)cmService).getResponseHeader(BiBus_NS, BiBus_H);

        try 
        {
            CMbibus = (BiBusHeader)temp.getValueAsType(new QName (BiBus_NS, BiBus_H));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (CMbibus != null)
        {
            ((Stub)cmService).setHeader(BiBus_NS, BiBus_H, CMbibus);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main class, which connects to Cognos BI and calls the
     * method doWork(), containing the specific code for this sample
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        GetOrphanMyFolders mainClass = new GetOrphanMyFolders();

        mainClass.connectToCognos();

        // If Anonymous is disabled, then logon
        if (nameSpaceID.length() > 0) 
        {
            mainClass.logon(nameSpaceID, userName, password);
        }

        //get all the CAMIDs related to the My Folders searchpath
        String[] listOfMyFolders = mainClass.getAllMyFoldersSearchPaths(nameSpaceID);
        String[][] listOfCamIds = mainClass.getAllCIs(nameSpaceID);
        Vector<String> orphanedMyFolders = new Vector<String>();

        // find a my folder that does not have an existing owner from the ldap 
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfMyFolders.length; i++)
        {
            if (listOfMyFolders[i] != null )
            {
                if (listOfMyFolders[i].endsWith("[@name='My Folders']")) 
                {
                    int y = 0;
                    for (y = 0; y < listOfCamIds[0].length - 1; y++) 
                    {
                        String test = listOfCamIds[0][y];
                        if (listOfMyFolders[i].indexOf(test) >= 0) 
                        {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!found) 
                    {
                        //  String userName = getUserNameFromCamid(listOfMyFolders[i]);
                        System.out.println(listOfMyFolders[i] + " does not have an associated user");
                        orphanedMyFolders.add(listOfMyFolders[i]);
                    }
                    found = false;
                }               
            }
        }

        // Now we need to take the list of orphaned My Folders and move them to the 
        // public folders so that the content can be examined.
        for (int x = 0; x < orphanedMyFolders.size(); x++)
        {
            mainClass.moveMF2PF(orphanedMyFolders.elementAt(x).toString(), targetLocation);
        }
        System.out.println("Done ....");
    }
}
```

Comment: those are the only 2 errors?

Comment: How are you running the program? How have you set the classpath?

Comment: No, there is about a 100 errors.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I'm trying to compile this program first.

Comment: @jrara there is an issue with `com.cognos.developer.schemas.bibus._3.PropEnum;` then. Thats why Oli is asking about classpath

Comment: The classes that you have imported, are those too provided by IBM? If yes, have you compiled them first, and placed them in the classpath?

Comment: I think I have to set CLASSPATH first. @RohitJain I think those classes are also provided by IBM, I have installed SDK from IBM, and I think those are included in the SDK.

Comment: you can find axisCognosClient.jar in cognos install directory %COGNOS_INSTALL_DIR%/c8/webapps/p2pd/WEB-INF/lib. Include this directory in your classpath when you compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample `GetOrphanMyFolders.java` is using classes defined in external libraries (i.e. jars) that should be available in `Cognos 8 SDK` (usually under `C8_INSTALLATION_DIR/sdk/lib`), I believe you should be looking for `cognosClient.jar` or `axisCognosClient.jar`

Since you are new to java, it will be cumbersome to compile this using `javac` and add external jars to the classpath. I would recommend that you use [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

After downloading/installing it (simply unzip to whatever directory you like), create a `New Java Project`, add `GetOrphanMyFolders.java` under the `src` package (copy/paste or drag/drop).
Then [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766854/how-to-import-new-apis-into-java-eclipse-ini4j/14766918#14766918) to know how you can add libraries to your project classpath.

It will be much easier than figuring out how to do this with `javac -cp`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that cognos jar is currently invisible. Hence, the compiler fails to resolve references to the classes that are packaged in this jar.

You can find axisCognosClient.jar in cognos install directory

```
 %COGNOS_INSTALL_DIR%/c8/webapps/p2pd/WEB-INF/lib
```

Include this directory in your classpath when you compile.
This jar includes all the classes you refer to in import statements.

Comment: Thanks, I have now in the CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib;C:\Program Files\ibm\cognos\c10_64\webapps\p2pd\WEB-INF\lib but I get the same error when trying to compile.

Comment: AxisCognosClient.jar seems to be in several places in my installation but not in the webapps\p2pd\WEB-INF\lib directory. I changed CLASSPATH to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\lib;C:\Program Files\ibm\cognos\c10_64\sdk\java\lib but that did not change the situation.

Comment: how do you compile ? (or where the classpath you mentioned is mused?)

Comment: I'm compiling using javac.exe to compile: javac.exe GetOrphanMyFolders.java from the command line.

Comment: Mind to post whole command as well as the directory you are running it from?

Comment: I see that you run on Windows. Try to copy cognoscenti jar to some location, so the path woul not contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I copied the contest of C:\Program Files\ibm\cognos\c10_64\sdk\java\lib into d:\temp\jars and put this path into CLASSPATH. But I get the same errors.

Answer (score 3):

It's usually the first reported errors that matter. Fixing these will fix the rest. If the first errors look something like this:
GetOrphanMyFolders.java:19: error: package com.cognos.developer does not exist
import com.cognos.developer.*;
^

Then you need to follow some IBM instructions to download these packages and add them to your classpath.

If already downloaded, try http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21343429

Answer (score 2):

You are intializing properties array of PropEnum type. Might be PropEnum dont have canBurst and capabilities defined as attribute.

Just try to remove spaces between
 {PropEnum.canBurst      ,PropEnum.capabilities   ,} 
to 
{PropEnum.canBurst,
PropEnum.capabilities,}. Spaces should not be the problem.